# Import XML > Convert CSV > Exclude column

Tags: php, xml, csv

I've created a PHP file to convert a XML file to CSV file. XML is import from external host.

Convert works very well. CSV file is created but now, I need to exclude some columns on the XML file before import or before converting to CSV.

My code:

```
    <?php
/* CONVERSION XML > CSV */
function convertXmlToCsvFile($xml_file_input, $csv_file_output, $nomLien) 
{
    $tableauTailles = array('XS','S','M','SM','ML','L','XL','XXL','T1','T2','T3','T4','X1','X2','X3') ;
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file_input);        
    $output_file = fopen($csv_file_output, 'w');        
    $header = false;
    
    $donneesSmiffys = 'ProductCode;ProductName;Size;BrochureDescription;WebDescription;WashingInstructions;RRP;StockQty;VatRate;Gender;PackType;PackQty;Audience;Colour;ETA;BarCode;Price1;Price2;Price3;Break1;Break2;Break3;unit_size;carton;stdPrice1;stdPrice2;stdPrice3;stdBreak1;stdBreak2;stdBreak3;Photo;CatalogueCode;CatalogueName;Catalogue;acc_code1;acc_code2;acc_code3;acc_code4;acc_code5;alt_code1;alt_code2;alt_code3;alt_code4;alt_code5;FrontShot;art_cat;Seasonal;p_list2;DropDate;ThemeName;Theme1;GroupID;GroupName;GroupID1;ThemeGroup1;GroupID2;ThemeGroup2;GroupID3;ThemeGroup3;EF_Price;EF_Qty;unit_length;unit_width;unit_height;unit_weight;unit_qty;inner_length;inner_width;inner_height;inner_weight;inner_qty;outer_length;outer_width;outer_height;outer_weight;outer_qty;GenericCode;HasImageRights;Safety;Composition;AmazonAsins
' ;
    
    foreach($xml as $key => $value)
    {
        // TRAITEMENT SHEET         
        $tabValeur = get_object_vars($value) ;
                
        
        // SIZE         
        preg_match('/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)/', $tabValeur["ProductCode"], $size);
        preg_match('/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})/', $tabValeur["ProductCode"], $size2);
        if (in_array($size[2], $tableauTailles)) $taille = $size[2] ;
        elseif (in_array($size2[2], $tableauTailles)) $taille = $size2[2] ;
        else $taille = '' ;
        
        // REFERENCE
        $donneesSmiffys .= 'SM' . $tabValeur["ProductCode"] . ';'               
            . $tabValeur["ProductName"] . ';'
            . $taille . ';'
            . $tabValeur["BrochureDescription"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["WebDescription"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["WashingInstructions"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["RRP"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["StockQty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["VatRate"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Gender"] . ';'
            . str_replace(';',',',$tabValeur["PackType"]) . ';'
            . $tabValeur["PackQty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Audience"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Colour"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["ETA"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["BarCode"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Price1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Price2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Price3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Break1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Break2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Break3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_size"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["carton"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdPrice1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdPrice2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdPrice3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdBreak1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdBreak2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["stdBreak3"] . ';'
            . $photos . ';'
            . $tabValeur["CatalogueCode"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["CatalogueName"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Catalogue"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["acc_code1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["acc_code2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["acc_code3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["acc_code4"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["acc_code5"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["alt_code1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["alt_code2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["alt_code3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["alt_code4"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["alt_code5"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["FrontShot"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["art_cat"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Seasonal"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["p_list2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["DropDate"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["ThemeName"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Theme1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GroupID"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GroupName"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GroupID1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["ThemeGroup1"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GroupID2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["ThemeGroup2"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GroupID3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["ThemeGroup3"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["EF_Price"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["EF_Qty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_length"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_width"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_height"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_weight"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["unit_qty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["inner_length"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["inner_width"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["inner_height"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["inner_weight"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["inner_qty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["outer_length"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["outer_width"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["outer_height"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["outer_weight"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["outer_qty"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["GenericCode"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["HasImageRights"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Safety"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["Composition"] . ';'
            . $tabValeur["AmazonAsins"] . '
';
    
        unset($size) ;
    }
    
    // WRITING FILE
    $file = fopen($csv_file_output, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $donneesSmiffys);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

How can I do this? My need: exclude some $tabValeur from original file (I must keep to use 2 values: $tabValeur["ProductCode"] and $tabValeur["StockQty"]) in CSV file.

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a mapping array for CSV columns to XML columns. Only what's in the array will be considered for the conversion.

Example code:

```
$map = [
    'ProductCode' => 'ProductCode', // same name 
    'SomeCSVColumn' => 'SomeXMLNode', // different name
];

foreach($map as $csvCol => $xmlCol) {
    if (isset($theCSVRow[ $csvCol ])) {
          // create XML node, depending on the XML parser used
          $xml->addChild($xmlCol, $theCSVRow[ $csvCol ]);
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to modify the map, add or remove any field from the conversion.

Comment: Hello, thank's. If I understand this, it's from CSV to XML? From XML to CSV, I'll must just replace CSV to XML (ie :foreach($map as $xmlCol => $csvCol) {
    if (isset($theXMLRow[ $xmlCol ])) {
          // create XML node, depending on the XML parser used
          $csv->addChild($csvCol, $theXMLRow[ $xmlCol ]);
    }

Comment: doesn't really matter, the map works the other way around as well.. only you collect all CSV data into an array, not creating XML elements

Comment: I must have made an error somewhere. The CSV file generated from the XML file does not take into account the mapping. It recovers all columns of the XML file. I placed the code just before the CSV file writing script